# How to use libpng in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, visual-studio-2015, libpng

I am using boost generic image library and it requires libpng. I built libpng and obtained the files libpng.lib, zlib.lib and libpngd.lib. When I tried to compile my project, Visual Studio gives a fatal error

```
fatal error LNK1120: 21 unresolved externals
```

with a bunch of unresolved external symbols like `_png_set_sig_bytes` and `_png_read_row`. What's going on here and how to solve it?

Comment: first check that  you're linking with library

Comment: So you *built* libpng and friends- good.  Are you sure you've *included* these libraries in your .exe project's "link"?  Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx

Comment: @paulsm4 I have included these libraries in the include directories, library directories and the linker's additional library directories. It still generates the error.

Comment: I use libpng and have no issues.  So if you say you're doing everything correctly, unless we see your machine, there is nothing really that can be done except to say "you're doing something wrong that you think you're doing correctly".

Comment: Are you explicitly including "libpng.lib", "zlib.lib" and "libpngd.lib" in your .exe's link command?  PS: You don't "include a library" in an "include directory" :(  The include directory contains headers. Which seem to be working - you're compiling successfully.

Comment: @raytracer *how to solve it?*  By making sure you are 1) linking with the correct libraries, and 2) that the libraries actually do contain the functions that are not found (names are not mangled, for example)   Obviously you're not doing 1), 2), or both, but which one(s)?  We don't know -- that's for you to figure out at this point since we don't have access to your project (or computer).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I basically followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XxVebzK3ac) for building the .libs. The difference is that I'm using VS2015 instead of 2010.

Comment: You could also use any number of [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=libpng) packages that provide libpng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

```
To add .lib files as linker input in the development environment

    Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see Setting Visual C++ Project Properties.

    Click the Linker folder.

    Click the Input property page.

    Modify the Additional Dependencies property.
```

You must do this; explicitly specifying "libpng.lib", "zlib.lib" and "libpngd.lib" in your .exe's link command.

Answer (score 0):

So this is coming from a complete simple minded moron so maybe this'll be helpful....it took me a little while to grasp. Basically, you're downloading the source code. That means, that you have to be the one to compile the source code.

Windows can compile programs that are written in C in the command prompt. You have to build the program, and it spits out a .dll or a .lib file. That or those are the files that you link to visual studio application.

You set dependencies to the header files which is usually like the source codes root folder or wherever all those .h files are.

You then set the linker to link to the .dll or .lib file(s). In Boost C++'s case, you need to link to a 'lib' folder.

I think what you need is to go over and completely grasp the basics. Here's a link from Microsoft on how Windows can compile C programs from the command prompt:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compile-a-c-program-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019